# How to avoid repetition when "factoring" a Haskell function into two functions with various intermediary types?

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

Consider the following Haskell code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Data.Singletons.TH

singletons [d| data SimpleType = Aaa | Bbb | Ccc | Ddd
                                 deriving (Read)
             |]

-- each SimpleType value has an associated type
type family Parsed (t :: SimpleType) :: * where
  Parsed Aaa = [Int]
  Parsed Bbb = Maybe Int
  Parsed Ccc = (Int, Int)
  Parsed Ddd = Int

forth :: SSimpleType t -> Int -> Parsed t
forth SAaa x = [x,x*2,x*3]
forth SBbb x = Just x
forth SCcc x = (1337, x)
forth SDdd x = x

back :: SSimpleType t -> Parsed t -> Int
back SAaa [_, y, _] = y + 5
back SBbb (Just y) = y - 7
back SCcc (y1, y2) = y1 + y2
back SDdd y = y * 2

helper b = back b . forth b

go :: SimpleType -> Int -> Int
go Aaa = helper SAaa
go Bbb = helper SBbb
go Ccc = helper SCcc
go Ddd = helper SDdd

main = do
  -- SimpleType value comes at run-time
  val <- readLn
  putStrLn $ show $ go val 100
```

Is it possible to avoid the repetition when `go` is defined? In other words, is there a way to write something like:

```
go val = helper (someMagicFunction val)
```

- singletons do not have to be a part of the solution,
- ... but the idea that `go` is factored into `forth` and `back` with intermediary types dependent on `Simple` should be preserved.

Comment: You can make a helper type `helper b = back b . forth b` and then call `helper` with the correct values (so `go Aaa = helper SAaa; go Bbb = helper`, etc.)

Comment: Not at all related to a solution, but you could make `Parsed` a [closed type family](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#closed-type-families) instead of an open one.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for the suggestion. I edited the question and took your idea into account. Still, the problem remains - I need to list all the values when defining `go`. (The code in my question is a simplified version of a real problem, when I have 30 values rather than 4.)

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky Thanks! I improved the code snippet accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`toSing` from `SingKind`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.4/singletons-2.5.1/Data-Singletons.html#v:toSing) to convert a value of `SimpelType` to a value of `SomeSing SimpleType`, which is an existentially quantified wrapper around `Sing SimpleType`. You can then unwrap that value to get `Sing SimpleType`, which you can then pass to `back` and `forth`:

```
go :: SimpleType -> Int -> Int
go val x =
  case toSing val of
    SomeSing s -> back s $ forth s x
```

An instance of `SingKind` is generated for you (among many other things) by the `singletons` splice that you're using.

Note that, while a single-branch `case` is asking to be a `let`, this wouldn't compile:

```
go val x =
  let (SomeSing s) = toSing val
  in back s $ forth s x
```

This is prohibited, because `let` can be recursive, and since unwrapping a GADT may bring new types into context, it may result in creating an infinite type. A `case` branch, on the other hand, cannot be recursive, so this works. (credit for this explanation to @HTNW)

But a helper function would also work:

```
go val x = helper $ toSing val
    where
      helper (SomeSing s) = back s $ forth s x
```

Comment: case works where let doesn’t because it imposes an ordering. The scrutinee cannot recursively refer to any results of the match. You need this order because pattern matching on a GADT not only results in values, but can result in types (but the binding of those types to variables are invisible). Thus, it’s OK for values to be recursive, but not for types. We expect let to be (potentially) recursive, so it’s not allowed, but case is allowed.

Comment: @HTNW yes, this totally makes sense, thank you for the hint. I have updated the answer.